# Toggle Animate css classes on slick carousel slide change

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js, animate.css

I am making a slider using `slick carousel` and i want `caption` animation using `animate` css while the slide is `active`.

The animation works fine on first slide when load but after that, the animation is not working on other slides.

Here is my `HTML`

```
<div id="hero-slider">
  <div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/500/abstract/1" alt="">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>We push the edge of</h3>
      <h2>what’s<br/>possible.123</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/500/abstract/2" alt="">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>We push the edge of</h3>
      <h2>what’s<br/>possible.456</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the `SCSS`

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#hero-slider {
    .caption {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10%;
        top: 10%;

        h2,h3 {
            color: white;
        }
    }
}
```

and the `jQuery` which i am using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#hero-slider').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 4000,
  dots: true,
  fade: true
});

if ($('.slick-slide').hasClass('slick-active')) {
    $('.caption').addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
  } else {
    $('.caption').removeClass('animated fadeInLeft');
  }
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tshmycL5/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to reapply the animation to each slide you can do something like this,
beforeChange will trigger before each slide in this you are first removing the classes and then applying slowly, so from that you can easily add the class again and show the effect.

```
 $("#hero-slider").on("beforeChange", function() {

    $('.caption').removeClass('animated fadeInLeft').hide();
    setTimeout(() => {    
      $('.caption').addClass('animated fadeInLeft').show();

    }, 1000);

  })
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tshmycL5/3/)

alternatively, you can use delay too

```
  $('.caption').removeClass('animated fadeInLeft')
  .hide().delay(1000).addClass('animated fadeInLeft').show();
```

Comment: its working exactly as i wanted, Appreciate that...Thanks very much... Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution without `setTimeout`: http://jsfiddle.net/tshmycL5/5/